# Why is debug not working on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I'm just a begginer with C#, I wanted to start to code but when I try to debug my code, the debug part is not avaiable to be used, I'm not sure what's wrong with the app or if it's a problem with my computer, which runs Windows 11

Hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance.
[image: Here's the problem]

I tried to uninstall visual studio several times, also watched some videos related to it but it was a complete waste of time.

Comment: The "Miscellaneous files" makes it look like your .cs file is not part of a project. Create a new Console App project and add your code to the default program.cs that appears.

Comment: You may want to link to specific video you've watched (preferably from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/getting-started/) and specify steps you've taken to get to the point you stuck (note that SO questions need to contain details as text inline in the question - images, videos and external links should be used only for additional info).

Comment: To extend @AlexK. 's comment, maybe you simply didn't open the `*.sln` (Solution) or `*.csproj` (Project) file but instead opened the `*.cs` (a file containing `c#` code) file directly.

Comment: As a beginner, you should stick close to official tutorials like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2022 which maximizes the probability of successful execution. Any imagination of yours or an official guide from another source can miss critical steps and lead to unnecessary frustration. This does not only apply to C#, but any other programming languages.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, any update of this issue, have you checked my answer? Let me know if it works or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your situation:

[image]

This issue comes from your code is not be recognized as Project/Solution.

C# is different from the language like python, open the script file directly will not make it be able to debug/run.

So the solution is creating a minimal structure.

You can follow the below steps to start a demo C# code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After the above steps, you will be able to debug the C# code:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Check to see if you are running in debug mode or release mode.

Comment: How can I check that?